# Value is returning Incorrectly

Tags: excel, vba, double

I am really confused with this one. I know it's probably something simple, but I can't seem to figure it out. I am essentailly creating a price calculator, and this is the most vital part of the macro.

```
Dim z As Double
For z = 7 To 8 Step 1
  If ActiveSheet.Cells(z, 10).Value = "" Then

    '''Dim Ref1 As Double
    '''Set Ref1 = Sheets("Ref").Cells(o, 4).Value
    Dim o As Double
    For o = 5 To 150 Step 1
        If ActiveSheet.Cells(z, 20).Value = Sheets("Ref").Cells(o, 3).Value Then
            MsgBox "Found: " & Sheets("Ref").Cells(o, 4).Value
            ActiveSheet.Cells(z, 10).Value = Sheets("Ref").Cells(o, 4).Value
            Exit Sub
        Else
        End If
    Next o

  Else
  End If
Next z
```

So the MsgBox returns the value I am looking for, but it is rounded to only 4 decimal places. I need more, but that isn't as big of a problem as the fact that the cell is then populated by zero, not the value that was in the MsgBox. I can't figure out why, considering they are both:

```
 Sheets("Ref").Cells(o, 4).Value
```

You can see I began to create a Double variable for the value (Ref1). I thought that maybe the '.Value' was rounding to a whole number when it populates the cell,  but I got a 400 error when trying to use this.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: have you checked the format of the cell you're populating to make sure it's not set to show 0 decimals?

Comment: Yes I did, I was actually trying to reformat it with VBA before it runs the for loop with this:


    'ActiveSheet.Range("J7:J300").NumberFormat = "$#,##0.0000000000"
'ActiveSheet.Range("J7:J300").NumberFormat = "0.0000000000"


It only adds more zero's to the zero value. (I was trying two different formats)

Comment: Not related, but `o` should be a `Long`, not a `Double`.

Comment: It was a long before, I was trying anything and everything just to see a change.

Comment: The only way I can replicate this is if the cell format of the target cell is "Fraction".  How is it set up on your worksheet?

Comment: Currency - 10 Decimal Places. The actual value in the cell is just "0", so the format isn't really the issue here I think.

Comment: I can't replicate this with my own sample data. Screenshots of the 2 sheets would help.

Comment: Put this right before the `Exit Sub` - `MsgBox ActiveSheet.Cells(z, 10).Value = Sheets("Ref").Cells(o, 4).Value` Does it show "True"?

Comment: The actual data is confidential, so let me recreate something similar:
http://imgur.com/a/Qzdsq

The Columns in green are the columns of interest.

Comment: WHAT? It says false, but that doesn't make sense.....

Comment: How can it equal false if the IF statement specifically looks for it to be true?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So I guess I was on the right track before, I fixed the 400 error when trying to define the Value as a Double. This is my final, working code:

```
'Find Price
Dim z As Long
For z = 7 To 8 Step 1
If ActiveSheet.Cells(z, 10).Value = "" Then


    Dim o As Long
    For o = 5 To 150 Step 1
        If ActiveSheet.Cells(z, 20).Value = Sheets("Ref").Cells(o, 3).Value Then

            Dim RefVal As Double
            RefVal = Sheets("Ref").Cells(o, 4).Value
            ActiveSheet.Cells(z, 10).Value = RefVal

        Else
        End If
    Next o

Else
End If
Next z
```